# Repeated Measures in R, SAS or SPSS: Whale Body Temperature Data

Tags: r, time-series, repeated-measures, nonparametric, sas

I have a question regarding a repeated measures experiment. I have 5 whales (randomly selected) that I recorded body temperature on. Data was collected via satellite, programmed to transmit records at 2-minute intervals, but data for each whale are not a complete time-series data set (i.e. unbalanced records/missing data points).

A state-space model was creating using the whale's GPS location to determine what state each whale was in while tracked at sea. The states are the following: resident foraging, resident transiting, and post-resident transiting.

I've partitioned the body temperature data into the 3 states. I have also divided up the body temperature data into 2 diel periods: daytime and nighttime.

So I have two subplot factors: Diel (2 levels: day and night) and State (3 levels: res. forage, res. transiting, post-res. transiting).

I have more than 500 body temperature values for each state/condition for all 5 whales, and I have more than 1000  body temperature values for daytime and nighttime periods for all whales. But again, I don't have the same number of data points for all whales, due to lack of satellite transmissions and the fact that there were differences among individual whales (e.g. some foraged for longer periods).

Can anyone offer non-parametric statistical advice (data transformations were all unsuccessful) for setting up a model analyze the effect of daytime/nighttime and state (and the interaction between these factors) on whale body temperature in R, SAS, or SPSS?

Would be happy to explain more about the data or experimental design.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: I am not sure, but from what you are saying this sounds like a time-series problem; with such a lot of observations and such a small N, approaches from that field may work better. If you agree, you should add the time-series tag so that the time series experts (not me!) will see it.

if you don't agree, then in `SAS` look into PROC GLIMMIX and in `R` look into `nlme`.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I've added a 'time-series' tag. Thanks also for you're advice on the SAS and R packages, which I'll be looking more into. I look forward to hearing more feedback from others (including time-series experts) on how to correctly analyze this type of data.

Comment: What is your research question? That is, are you interested in intraindividual change over time or simply between the states you have identified?

Comment: Hi, I am interested in the within-subject change over time (i.e. changes between the states I've identified).

Comment: @Jim. Assuming temprature is continuous, I think this can be acheived in PROC MIXED. YOU would have three level 1 factors; time, diel, and state. Of course, if you are interested in how diel and state alter the effect of time, then you would need to include interactions. Your level 2 model would be examining between-whale effects...maybe type of whale, size, etc. It all depends on your research questions, but that is the basic approach.

Comment: @toomuchpj Unfortunately, my data are not distributed normally and all data transformations were unsuccessful. From what I've read about PROC MIXED, my data do not meet the assumptions of PROC MIXED modeling. Also, my temperature data is continuous. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: You can request robust standard errors in PROC MIXED using the EMPIRICAL option. Also, depending on the nature of your data at level 1, have you considered how the error distribution is specified?